# Django authentication and Ajax - URLs that require login

Tags: javascript, python, django, authentication

I want to add some [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)-niceness to my Django-coded website.

In my Django code, I use the `@login_required` decorator from `django.contrib.auth.decorators` to mark which view requires authentication. The default behavior when a not authenticated user clicks it is to redirect him/her to login page, and then pass the target page.

What I saw on some sites, and really liked, is that when user clicks a link leading to a place restricted to logged-only users, instead of getting redirected to a login page, he/she gets a popup window (via JavaScript) asking him/her to log in or register. There's no redirection part, so no need for a user to use the "back" key if he/she decides he/she really doesn't like the website enough to waste the time registering.

So, the qestion is:  how would you manage the task of automatically marking some links as "restricted" so JavaScript can handle their `onclick` event and display a "please log in" popup?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, and, like you, I would like a simple decorator to wrap around a Django ajax view in order to handle authentication in the same way that I have other views.  One approach that seems promising to me is to use such a decorator in conjunction with JavaScript that looks for a certain value in the response.

Here is <s>first</s> revised draft of the decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def ajax_login_required(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        json = simplejson.dumps({ 'not_authenticated': True })
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
    return wrapper
```

Here is the view:

```
@ajax_login_required
def ajax_update_module(request, module_slug, action):
    # Etc ...
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

And here is the JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$.post('/restricted-url/', data, function(json) {
    if (json.not_authenticated) {
        alert('Not authorized.');  // Or something in a message DIV
        return;
    }
    // Etc ...
});
```

---

**EDIT**: I've attempted to use `functools.wraps`, as suggested.  I have not actually used this decorator in working code, so beware of possible bugs.

Comment: It's maybe worth pointing out that you can use the `functools.wraps` decorator around `def wrap` to avoid the assignments to `wrap.__doc__`, `wrap.__dict__`, and `wrap.__name__` (which isn't mentioned in this answer but should be done). See http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps

Comment: @Anders: please go ahead and edit the response to incorporate the change.  I haven't been working in Python for a while, and I don't want to mess it up.

Comment: Shouldn't the view rather send a 401 HTTP status instead ?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is accepted answer. This works for ajax requests only. What if user clicked a link to access a restricted view? Should you change all those related client code to use initiate ajax requests?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a page template possibility.

1. You could pass a `LINK_VIA` (or something) that you provide as `onClick="return popup(this, 'arg')"` or `None`.  Each link would be `<A HREF="link" {{LINK_VIA}}>some text</a>`.

   - For anonymous sessions, `LINK_VIA` has a value.
   - For logged in sessions, `LINK_VIA` is None
2. You could use an `{% if %}` statement around your `<A HREF=...>` tags.  This seems wordy.
3. You could write your own custom tag with for `{% link_via %}`.  I'm not familiar enough with this, but you can provide the link and text as strings and your tag can generate one of two kinds of links.

Comment: What I'm wondering is how to determine from template's point of view if the view that the link leads to is decorated with @login_required or not...

Comment: The template doesn't have random links.  It has specific links you specifically designed and coded in the template.  I suggest you change each link you specifically put in the template.

Answer (score 5):

I would agree with [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312925/django-authentication-and-ajax-urls-that-require-login#313015)

Make a check in the template, if the user is logged in, just put the link as usual, if not, put something like

```
<a href="{{link}}" onclick="return login_popup()">
```

where login_popup would return false if the user says cancel.

This could be probably be done much easier in [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) through its [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/templates#macros).

If the template doesn't know which urls require the user to login, you probably need to re-consider your design.

If you must, I guess you can do the same thing that the django url dispatcher does to discover the view function. 
see: `django.core.urlresolvers`

once you've grabbed the view function you can check if it's decorated with @login_required.

This would be done in a custom tag probably. 
If you use Jinja2, you won't need the tag, just implement the function and expose it to the Environment, it's simple but you'll have to do a bit of reading on the API of Jinja2)

Comment: I'm wildly late to the party on this one, but whatever: This is non-ideal only because the user could have followed a direct link to the page in question, in which case the login required popup methodology here will break.

Answer (score 2):

Built off of [Eric Walker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523196/5044937) solution, but for Django 2.0

```
# Standard Imports
import functools
import django.http

def ajax_login_required(view_func):
    @functools.wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

        return django.http.JsonResponse('Unauthorized', status=401, safe=False)

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is proposed version of the decorator with wrap.__doc__ , wrap.__name__

```
from functools import wraps

def ajax_login_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        json = simplejson.dumps({ 'not_authenticated': True })
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')  
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```