# Django redirecting to another view with a bound form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-1.3

I am using `Python 2.7`, `Django 1.3.1`.

I am trying to implement a sign in functionality that can be called from arbitrary page and redirects to the same page without any code duplication. The current way that I have is that I have two views: one for the homepage and one for sign in. I want to be able redirect from sign_in view to the home view with a *bound form*. The main problem is that when the user enters incorrect data (e.g wrong password) I want to redirect to the same page but want to send the context of the original form. I want to be able to do this without explicitly calling the view function since I want to be able to do it from arbitrary page. How do I do this? My current attempts always return an unbound form in case the data is invalid.

My current code is (simplfied):

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='home'),
    url(r'sign_in/^$', 'signin', name='sign_in')
)
```

`views.py`

```
def index(request, loginForm=LoginForm)
    extra_context = dict()
    extra_context['login_form'] = loginForm
    return direct_to_template(request, 'home.html', extra_context=extra_context)

def signin(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login_form = LoginForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if login_form.is_valid():
            # login user 
        redirect_view = reverse('home')
        return redirect(redirect_view, kwargs={'loginForm': login_form})
        # I also tried:  
        # return redirect(redirect_view, loginForm=login_form)
        # what works is:
        # return index(request, loginForm = login_form)
```

`home.html`

```
<form action="{% url sign_in %}" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with reverse.  Reverse gets you a path /my-homepage/

The django paradigm for this is to use a hidden "next" variable set to the initial page.

```
#In your template
<input type="hidden" value="{{ request.path }}" name="next" />
```

Then, on success return an HttpResponseRedirect to next:

```
     if login_form.is_valid():
         # login user 
         return HttpResponseRedirect(form.cleaned_data['next'])
```

This is durable, because if there is an issue, you display a form with errors on the /account/login/ page with the hidden next variable and the user still gets back to where they were.

Comment: This is simply redirecting to the orignal page upon success. I am concerned when the login_form is not valid. I would like to redirect to the view corresponding to the original page (yes, the link to that could be obtained through the 'next' parameter) with the bound form indicating errors.

Comment: That could be cute, but could also be a disaster.  If there are errors, don't you want the user on a single page with their focus explicitly on fixing the error?

Comment: Yes. That is one feasible solution, but the downside being that the user is being redirected to a page that looks different. I want to know if the failed redirect can be done to the same page. Seems like the answer is no?

Comment: if you really want "same page" errors, use an ajax system that degrades to displaying the errors on its own page.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312925/django-authentication-and-ajax-urls-that-require-login