# User authentication in django : Logging in using api rather than form

Tags: django, authentication

I'm using Django, and am looking to have the option to login both using a web page (the standard way) and through a separate client process (for the sake of my testing, using python requests)

I've seen [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891322/setting-up-a-user-login-in-python-django-using-json-and-have-no-idea-where-to) about doing an ajax login, but my understanding of this solution is that it would be vulnerable to a CSRF attack, as it's only taking the POSTed username/password.

What I'd like to do is request a CSRF token (with a GET call to my custom /auth-api/login view), and then pass this in a POST call along with the username and password.

This is what I currently have in views.py

```
from django.middleware import csrf
from django.http import JsonResponse

def login( request ) :
    return JsonResponse( { 'csrf_token': csrf.get_token( request ) } )
```

From Python on the client end, I'm then doing: (I have verify=False here because I am currently using a self-signed SSL certificate for development purposes)

```
result = s.get( "https://<ip_addr>/auth-api/login", verify = False )
csrf_token = json.loads( result.text )['csrf_token']

s.post( "https://<ip_addr>/auth-api/login",
         verify = False,
         data = { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token,
                  'username': "<username>",
                  'password': "<password>" },
         cookies = dict( result.cookies ),
         headers = { 'X-CSRFToken': res.cookies['csrftoken'] } )
```

However, the text of the response to this tells me that the CSRF token is missing or incorrect. I am passing it in 3 places (the POST data, cookies and headers).

Am I missing something simple here, or should I be taking a different approach to this api kind of login?

Comment: The view does not have to care about the CSRF token, the middleware will already check that.

Comment: Don't I still need to include the 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' field in my POST response, though? And if so, where do I get this from?